# How to use environment variables for minio?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mongoose, mern, minio

I am creating a minio client like this:

```
  endPoint: process.env.END_POINT,
  port: parseInt(process.env.PORT),
  useSSL: false,
  accessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
});
```

But using environment variables in this way fails to connect to the minio bucket. Instead if i use hardcoded values, the client is created successfully.

Is there any way to use environment variables or any other way to keep the credentials secure?

Relevant code that I am using minio in:

```
      const filePath = req.file.path;
      const metaData = {
        "Content-Type": req.file.mimetype,
      };

      const bucketName = "abc";
      const objectName = req.file.originalname;

      minioClient.fPutObject(
        bucketName,objectName,filePath,metaData,
        async (err, etag) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading image:", err);
            return res.status(500).send("Error uploading the image.");
          }

          console.log("Image uploaded successfully: ", objectName);

          const username = req.user.username;
          const newPost = new Post({
            content: req.body.content,
            image: "http://localhost:9000/abc/" + objectName,
            username: username,
          });

const savedPost = await newPost.save();
```

Comment: Log the process.env property in your application, if it does not contain the property that is related to the minio, install dotenv model and import and configure it inside the file where you access the minio property using process.env.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({})
```

Comment: It correctly logs the properties, also i have installed dotenv package. @BennisonJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself by changing this

```
endPoint: process.env.END_POINT
```

to this

```
port: parseInt(process.env.MINIO_PORT)
```

There were two errors, firstly minio was running on a different port so I had to specify a different port and, secondly environment variables are treated as  strings, so using parseInt is a must so that it is stored correctly as an integer instead.